# What's Left? - a word puzzle

Tags: word, knowledge

A ship pulled into a harbor and everyone went ashore.

The first sailor off the boat went to the pub, and after his fifth ale began to **YD** so loudly they threw him in the drunk tank.

The second went to a fancy store to find a **EAD** for her lover, and hasn't decided yet.

The third picked a fight with a local - that was nearly his **FIEL**!

The fourth was trying to reinvent their look, and is still shopping for a **AN**.

The fifth loves animals, and won't leave without his newly adopted baby **ETH**.

The sixth went too close to a cliff and fell off the **LMBRI**.

The seventh loves **TOCK** so she's still watching footy.

The eighth was not rowdy but is quite large and had to be a **EFF** for the third!

After all this, their boat was left _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that

> these missing words when combined with the additional letters make up a name of towns/ cities/ areas from England.

1. > The first sailor off the boat went to the pub, and after his fifth ale began to cro(**YD**)on so loudly they threw him in the drunk tank.
2. > The second went to a fancy store to find a r(**EAD**)ing for her lover, and hasn't decided yet.
3. > The third picked a fight with a local - that was nearly his en(**FIEL**)d!
4. > The fourth was trying to reinvent their look, and is still shopping for a wig(**AN**).
5. > The fifth loves animals, and won't leave without his newly adopted baby lamb(**ETH**). (not sure)
6. > The sixth went too close to a cliff and fell off the e(**LMBRI**)dge.
7. > The seventh loves s(**TOCK**)port so she's still watching footy.
8. > The eighth was not rowdy but is quite large and had to be a sh(**EFF**)ield for the third!

Take the first letter of every answer and you get

> After all this, their boat was left **c r e w l e s s**.

Comment: Yes! Although 5 isn't quite right, you've got everything else spot on.

Comment: @Harfatum I've edited it. How about this time?

Comment: You've got it. That solution was NCHE-ful.